# Consolidating many Google App Engine apps into a single Application/UI experience

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

Looking at Google Cloud Console, which is arguably one of the best UIs when compared to other cloud providers:

[image]

On the left you have a list of say 'apps' which I assume are fairly independent applications developed by different teams, with different CI/CD processes etc.

From a user's perspective this is seen as one application with many 'apps/products'.

Now, let's say one has many independent running [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) applications how could one go about integrating these into a single application, which is/feels similar to how the current Google Cloud Console is setup?

Some features of the GAE apps are:

- All access are driven by [Google Cloud IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/), by using the IAP ([Google Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/)) in front of each app.
- The GAE applications are independent apps each with their own teams, code repos, review cycles, etc.

Are there any best practices, examples, frameworks, whitepapers, discussions out there which I could have a look at for some direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You App Engine app is created under you Google Cloud project and is structured as a top level container that includes the service, version and instance resources

[An Overview of App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/an-overview-of-app-engine).

> From a user's perspective this is seen as one application with many
>   'apps/products'.

You can use services on App Engine to simulate the "app/products" which will share common features and communicate with each other (Microservices behaviour).

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @marian.vladoi. - good suggestion.  I see that with GAE Standard one could have more than a 100 services all backed by different source repositories.  I'll give it a few days before marking this as the solution.

Comment: Let say one have 3 services (serv1, serv2, serv3) each hosted here: 
https://myapp.mysite.com/serv1, https://myapp.mysite.com/serv2, https://myapp.mysite.com/serv3

Each of these three are based on independent repositories and runtimes.

And the home page is https://myapp.mysite.com - how would one 'integrate' these services i.e. like Google Cloud Console, have a consistent menu structure, hosting each of these apps.  There is a frontend component (ie. left column of links and top level bar) which spans across all apps.

Comment: I understand that you would like to know how to communicate between services.The simplest approach for communicating with your App Engine service is to send targeted HTTP requests [Communicating Between Your Services](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/communicating-between-services) Also you can check [how requests are routed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/how-requests-are-routed)